# What is the kernel of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Consider the matrix \begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}
Why is the kernel equal to \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} rather than \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}?

Comment: Why do you think that the kernel consists solely of the zero vector?

Comment: Assuming that the underlying field is $\mathbb R$, the kernel cannot consist of a single vector. Did you mean the *spans* of these vectors?

Comment: The solution given for this problem in my textbook was the 1st column on the matrix, i.e. the zero vector. And yes, I did mean the span of the vector.

Answer (score 5):

The kernel is $$\{t\cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}:t\in \mathbb R\}$$...

It's easy to see that that this set is contained in the kernel (by matrix multiplication)...

By the Rank-nullity theorem the kernel is $1$-dimensional (the rank is $2$)...

Comment: How does this provide an answer?

Comment: @Michael Hoppe I've added some comments...

Answer (score 0):

The matrix is row-reduced.  You can read off the solutions to $A\vec x= \vec 0$ and see that the kernel consists of the vectors $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$ with $y=z=0$...